# Game development with Unity without Unity editor. Is it possible?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'd like to describe the situation.
My name is Constantine.
I'm blind. Completely blind.
Among blind programmers, there are those who develop audio games.
What does it look like?
Imagine GTA, Mafia, Call Of Duty, any shooter. Only without graphics, and without sight height. And you are guided by 3D sound, shoot at the sound, etc.
Recently, a lot of those who write in Python. But personally, I'd not trust Python with a good online project...
To work with a computer, we use screen access programs. Programs that voice everything on the computer screen.
You can read more about it here:
https://www.vincit.com/blog/software-development-450-words-per-minute
https://medium.com/free-code-camp/looking-back-to-what-started-it-all-731ef5424aec
Why can't we use video game engines?
Because not all of them are access to us. The most popular, Unity and Unreal Engine, are not available for our programs.
What is the problem with Unity?
Unity editor isn't accessible. Absolutely.
I don’t know with what tools it was developed, but navigation through the interface is unrealistic.
Blind developers have repeatedly written about this on Unity's official websites, but alas, they have not heard us for many years.
My question is:
How much needs to be done in the Unity editor? How is it possible and is it possible to write the game code in code editor without resorting to the Unity editor, or can this be minimized, which can be done on Autoit?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd like to know more about this, I couldn't find anything. Godot game engine might have some kind of support if you check this github issue: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/14011

Comment: That's very interseting. I have some idea about accesibility, I had a colleague while in the university who was blind and was studying computer engineering and was always writing code. He was really good at it but his problems were always similar to these.

The only problem I see is that, even though you can write code in Visual Studio and such tools, the Play Mode and the output window are the most needed in this situation... I don't really know how you could read the error messages and modify stuff in the UI.

It looks loke a very frustrating problem for you.

Comment: simple answer - yes, create extensions..

Answer (score 5):

Preface: I have no expertise in accessibility at all

## The short answer is quite a lot

A lot of unity is designed with the intention that a user can create a 'custom editor' script to quickly build their own tools and speed up their workflow. For this reason, a surprising amount of Unity's functionality can be controlled entirely through scripting. Instantiating objects, positioning them, adding components, setting up inter-object references, even creating prefabs or new scenes can be done in code. It may be tedious to do something that would be simple in editor, and you might find yourself having to write builder scripts that will run once to create some asset, but it should possible to do most things.

There are some things where using the editor is needed, such as building your game into a .exe, working with Uniy's source control and the likes, but those are arguably external to creating a game.

If anyone can think of anything that *must* be done in the editor with no reasonable work around please comment it below and I'll add it to my answer but as far as I am aware there is nothing you'll need to do that you cannot do.

You'll need to have the editor running, and you might have to click on it to force an update so some script will run and do something, but you shouldn't need to *use* the editor.

Comment: Also check out [this blog post](https://icodelikeagirl.com/2017/02/09/unity-accessibility-plugin-update-11-editor-accessibility-vs-app-accessibility/) about a plugin that has *very minimal* support for screen-reading error messages